# Is it possible to use Dio package but Shared Preferences package for caching?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to use Dio package for HTTP requests but the Shared Preferences package for caching?

Comment: Yes. You can use Dio Interceptors, create custom interceptor with shared pref logic

Answer (score 0):

Yes just create an interceptor that will manage caching.

### Code

Here's a basic implementation using shared_preferences:

```dart
class CachingInterceptor extends Interceptor {
  CachingInterceptor({
    this.cacheDuration = const Duration(minutes: 10),
  });

  final Duration cacheDuration;

  final _cacheService = SharedPrefsNetworkCacheService();

  @override
  void onRequest(
    RequestOptions options,
    RequestInterceptorHandler handler,
  ) async {
    final cacheKey = options.uri.toString();
    final cachedEntry = await _cacheService.getEntry(cacheKey);

    if (cachedEntry != null) {
      final response = _buildResponse(cachedEntry, options);
      return handler.resolve(response);
    }

    return handler.next(options);
  }

  @override
  void onResponse(Response response, ResponseInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    final statusCode = response.statusCode;

    // Only cache successful responses
    if (statusCode != null && statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300) {
      final entry = NetworkCacheEntry.fromResponse(
        response,
        cacheDuration,
      );
      await _cacheService.putEntry(entry);
    }

    return handler.next(response);
  }

  Response _buildResponse(
    NetworkCacheEntry cachedEntry,
    RequestOptions options,
  ) {
    return Response(
      requestOptions: options,
      statusCode: cachedEntry.statusCode,
      data: cachedEntry.value,
    );
  }
}

class SharedPrefsNetworkCacheService {
  bool _initialized = false;
  bool get initialized => _initialized;

  late final SharedPreferences _sharedPrefs;

  Future<void> _init() async {
    if (_initialized) return;

    _sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _initialized = true;
  }

  Future<NetworkCacheEntry?> getEntry(String key) async {
    if (!_initialized) await _init();

    final cachedEntry = _sharedPrefs.getString(key);
    if (cachedEntry == null) return null;

    final entry = NetworkCacheEntry.fromJson(
      jsonDecode(cachedEntry) as Map<String, dynamic>,
    );

    // Remove expired entries
    if (!entry.isValid) {
      await _sharedPrefs.remove(entry.key);
      return null;
    }

    return entry;
  }

  Future<bool> putEntry(NetworkCacheEntry entry) async {
    if (!_initialized) await _init();

    final json = jsonEncode(entry.toJson());
    return _sharedPrefs.setString(entry.key, json);
  }
}

class NetworkCacheEntry {
  const NetworkCacheEntry({
    required this.key,
    required this.statusCode,
    required this.value,
    required this.expiry,
  });

  factory NetworkCacheEntry.fromResponse(
    Response response,
    Duration cacheDuration,
  ) {
    return NetworkCacheEntry(
      key: response.requestOptions.uri.toString(),
      statusCode: response.statusCode,
      value: response.data,
      expiry: DateTime.now().add(cacheDuration),
    );
  }

  factory NetworkCacheEntry.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return NetworkCacheEntry(
      key: json['key'] as String,
      statusCode: json['statusCode'] as int?,
      value: json['value'],
      expiry: DateTime.parse(json['expiry'] as String),
    );
  }

  final String key;
  final int? statusCode;
  final dynamic value;
  final DateTime expiry;

  bool get isValid => expiry.isAfter(DateTime.now());

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'key': key,
      'statusCode': statusCode,
      'value': value,
      'expiry': expiry.toIso8601String(),
    };
  }
}
```

And just add the interceptor to your instance of dio:

```dart
final dioClient = Dio()..interceptors.add(DioCacheManager());
```

You can try a complete working example on zapp.run: https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-z7je06a67jf0?entry=lib%2Fmain.dart&file=lib%2Fmain.dart